# Activate Sqlite3 for php 7.2

Tags: php, apache, sqlite, pdo

Do you know how to activate sqlite for php? I have activated extensions but the sqlite drivers do not appear. In my php.ini I only have this:

```
;extension=bz2
;extension=curl
;extension=fileinfo
;extension=gd2
;extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=interbase
;extension=ldap
;extension=mbstring
;extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
extension=pdo_oci
extension=pdo_odbc
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop

; The MIBS data available in the PHP distribution must be installed.
; See http://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php
;extension=snmp

;extension=soap
;extension=sockets
extension=sqlite3
;extension=tidy
;extension=xmlrpc
;extension=xsl
```

Thank you

Comment: "_but the sqlite drivers do not appear_" What does that mean? Do not appear where? Did you restart your webserver? Did you edit the correct `php.ini` file?

Comment: They don't appear when I do 'phpinfo ()'. I restarted my service successfully, and only mysql and pgsql are activated.